# Geforce GTX-960 phantom prevents PC from boot

Tags: graphics-card

I bought a GTX-960 phantom, which I plugged into my PC but now it won't boot anymore. The only thing that shows up is the first screen wich says "American Megatrends" (Motherboard manufacturer).I can't even reach the Bios.

If I remove the graphic-card the Pc is working as normal.

My build at the moment is:

- Intel Core  i5 3450 (IvyBridge)
- 8 Gb DDR3 RAM
- Gigabyte GA-B75M-D3H
- 500 Gb ssd
- Thermaltake Berlin 630 Watt

I already changed the power supply with the same result.
I also tried the Graphic-card on another Pc with no errors.
Now I don't know what else to do or to check, to get the Graphic-card up and running.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the other power supply's wattage? Do you notice that the fans take a while to spin up or any LEDs are dim when you start it with the graphics card installed?

Comment: The CPU has a Core Voltage around 0.924V and there is not much more that uses power supply. One fan, CPU and the SSD. No I didn't notice anything weird, like dimming lights or something and the fans of the graphic card were working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have an Ivy Bridge CPU your motherboard is probably a bit on the older side and may need a BIOS update to work with newer GPUs. I personally had some similar sounding issues with a similarly aged motherboard when I got an HD7970 which was the first GPU to support PCI 3.0 and I needed a BIOS update to get it to work.

Comment: Thank you! I just updated the BIOS and now the PC boots as usual.

Comment: Glad I could help